# Empty Row Labels in PivotTable after adding descriptions as a measure

Tags: excel-2010, dax, powerpivot

I'm trying to use **Powerpivot** to help me summarize Actual and Committed Costs from a project. After some manipulations in Power query I managed to get the  [right structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHklL.png), but getting it in a powerpivottable is still a disaster.
As I also want to include **Descriptions** but keep the nice indented powerpivot Layout, I used a formula to convert the description to a measure using DAX. I found a formula online and tweeked it a bit so it would also work when there was more than 1 hit:

```
=IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES('Table1'[Description]))>1,FIRSTNONBLANK('Table1'[Description],0),VALUES('Table1'[Description]))
```

This gave a [more satisfying result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33d7e.png)

However there were two set-backs:

1. There are a lot of copies of the same descriptions creating empty Row labels (I don't want any Empty Row Labels)
2. When taking the description from the source table it doesn't take the result from the first match for the row label in my table.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Noting is wrong with the DAX and even from the images what you want is not clear. Please clear what you want and what is 1, 2 (red) in the image.

Comment: There are clearly two set-backs listed in the question. The 1,2 (red) in the image illustrate both of these set-backs. So what I want is:
1) A way to do this without having blank row labels
2) A formula that takes the correct "Description". The one I created works ok when there is only 1 hit. However for summary rows, where you have multiple hits, it displays a wrong value.